# How to check if a property has been set in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

My biggest issue here is when I have a property that can be nullable, but I want to check if it have been set, even if the value is `null`

Inside `MyComponent` I what I want to differ is this two cases

Passing `Foo` property

```
<MyComponent Foo="@foo" />

@code {
    public Foo foo { get; set; }
}
```

Not passing `Foo` property

```
<MyComponent  />
```

But inside `MyComponent`, in both cases, `Foo` will be `null`.

How can I know that `Foo` property is being passed, even if the value is the `default` value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override the SetParametersAsync method to inspect the parameters that are set or not. Even if the value is null.
If the parameter is not specified it will not be present in the collection.

E.g.

```
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
    {
        foreach(var prm in parameters)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Name: {prm.Name}");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Value: {prm.Value?.ToString()}");
        }

        await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);

    }
}
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.setparametersasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: This is not reliable depending on the situation.  If you decorate your parameter with `SupplyParameterFromQuery`, it will appear in `ParameterView` whether it is specified or not.  This is the technique I have used until now, but `SupplyParameterFromQuery` changes the game.  My old assumptions about how things work have caused me a lot of grief here, so do be aware.

Answer (score -1):

```
<h3>Component</h3>

@code {
    private bool _setFromOutside;
    private Foo _foo = new Foo(); //values set from inside of your component

    [Parameter]
    public Foo Foo
    {
        get => _foo;
        set
        {
            _setFromOutside = true;
            _foo = value;
        }
    }
}
```